# Accessing pixel value using cv::Mat::at operator

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1 (c++ api) and when I try to get the pixel value of colored image, I'm getting very strange results, instead of value number, output is something like this: ?, *, | etc. For example, the code is as follows:

```
cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread("Picture1.jpg");
std::cout << inputImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[0] << std::endl; //print B component
```

where x and y are coordinates from mouse callback function. I assume that type is wrong, do you have any idea what else could I use instead of Vec3b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html

Vec3b in OpenCV is `typedef Vec<uchar, 3> Vec3b;`. So, I guess you need to cast to integer in the cout process.

Something like `std::cout << (int) inputImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(x,y)[0] << std::endl; //print B component`

Comment: Yes, you were right, but I can not print everything I want, program crashes when I use two loops to access every pixel, it prints out maybe 100 values and than stops:

`for(int i=0; i<inputImage.rows; i++)
   for(int j=0; i<inputImage.cols; j++)
      std::cout << (int)inputImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0] << std::endl;`

Comment: _OpenCV Error: Assertion Failed_
something in line 552 in mat.hpp

Comment: No, I just created console app, and inserted those lines that I wrote here, just to see if it works.

Comment: Ok, the console app, must be using some assert functions. Anyway, check in your inner loop `for(int j=0; i<inputImage.cols; j++)` you are comparing with i, and increasing j.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that the problem happening because you are using "at(x, y)". Documentation says that the first argument should be "The 0-based row index" and second "The 0-based column index". So, you should either call at(y, x) or at(cv::Point(x, y)).

Comment: although this is right, that there likely is an error in the posted code (accessing .at(x,y) instead of .at(y,x)), the printing of strange characters instead of numbers still looks more like a typecasting problem.